# How to ping other users

Tags: support, chat, comments

What are the rules of pinging? You can ping a user on comments and in chat, but the rules for doing so aren't clear.

- You can ping a user by commenting on his post and by writing `@username` in a group of comments he previously commented in, but can you ping someone who has not previously commented?
- I've seen many people try (myself among them!) to ping a person in a question or answer by writing `@username` in the question/answer -- does that work?
- Pinging someone in chat -- only if they have participated in chat before?

Comment: Had no idea what to tag this....if you have a better idea leave me a comment or just fix it; thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technicalities of pinging someone in chat are outlined at [`http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#notifications`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#notifications), except that it omits an important bit of information: Another way to ping someone is by replying to his message in chat. This is done by clicking the arrow that appears when you hover your mouse over his message (which causes your message to start with a colon (`:`) and the numerical identifier of his message).

The technicalities of pinging someone in a comment (whether he posted a comment or a post (question or answer)) are outlined at [`https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-reply`](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-reply) and in greater detail at [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019).

You cannot ping anyone by typing something into a post (or edit summary).

Comment: The arrow referred to is in the bottom right corner, looks like a "return" symbol facing the wrong way.